# Github Search API: search for a file without giving the complete filename

Tags: github, github-api, github-search

I want to use the Github Search API to find all files that can be close to a given word.
For example, if i search for https://api.github.com/search/code?q=COPY+in:file,path+repo:yvonndjamen/Endevor i will receive 6 items matching my request because i gave the word "COPY"

But if i do the same request with: https://api.github.com/search/code?q=CO+in:file,path+repo:yvonndjamen/Endevor
There will not be any answer.

Is there a way to solve this problem and make a research like with the Github File Finder?
Over there when i just type "C" i get lots of results and i want to perform something like that with the Search API.

I want to be able to search for a letter ("C") or two ("CO") and get results where the API find files with those letters.

Comment: Based on the docs I don't think this is possible because you can't use wildcards. See: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search

Comment: @astrochun i really looked for it and though i could find a work around, but it is really not possible. Thank you

Comment: What was your workaround?

Comment: @astrochun since i wanted to implement my own frontend file finder, i gave it 3 search criteria. If the user look for "element", my backend make a request to Github with the "q" index -> "q=element_name"...If he gives an "extension", the request look like this "q=+extension=extension_name" and if he gives a location, the request use another url that gives every files present in the provided location